# React-Native with Redux Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, dispatch

I want to call an action from my componentWillMount() after the firebase auth manager says there is no authenticated user. This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { responsiveHeight, responsiveWidth, responsiveFontSize } from 'react-native-responsive-dimensions';

const ristImage = require('../assets/risto-landing.png');

class LandingScreen extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
     console.log('User Logged-in')
   } else {
     console.log('No Authenticated User')
     return(
  this.props.dispatch(clearState())
    )
   }
 });
  }

  fbLoginPress() {
  this.props.fbLogin();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <View>
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={styles.landingImageStyle}
            source={ristImage}
          />
          <Text style={styles.titleAppStyle}>Risto </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            large
            title="Sign in With Facebook"
            backgroundColor="#4068AD"
            icon={{ name: 'facebook-square', type: 'font-awesome' }}
            style={[styles.buttonStyle, styles.fbColor]}
            onPress={this.fbLoginPress.bind(this)}
          />

          <Button
            large
            title="Sign In or Sign Up With Email"
            icon={{ name: 'envelope', type: 'font-awesome' }}
            backgroundColor="#F8A443"
            style={[styles.buttonStyle, styles.emailColor]}
            onPress={Actions.emailLogin}
          />

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(LandingScreen);
```

Now, what I want is to call my action clearState() from my ./authAction files to clear back the initial state. Is my approach correct or is it also possible to call the dispatch action directly within my componentWillMount?

Then this is where my clearState() functions in actions/js:

```
export const clearState = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({type: SIGN_OUT});
  console.log('State re-initialized');
}
```

Comment: where is you componentWillMount. I cannot see it in your code

Comment: I have updated my code @stack26

Comment: @DrailanJohnTerrible see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` in the callback you provide to `onAuthStateChanged()` is not what you think it is. It is bound to something else that has not property named `props`. That's why you get that error. You can do two things to avoid that:

**1. Use an arrow function:**

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    ...
}
```

**2. bind the callback to your `this`.**

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((function(user) {
    ...
}).bind(this);
```

I prefer the first alternative.

Also if you pass an object of actions to your `connect()` function it will not inject `dispatch` into your props. Instead it will provide a function as a prop with the same name and already wrapped into a `dispatch()`.

From the [react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> [mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

That means you just have to call `this.props.clearState()`.

Comment: oh okay i'll try.

Comment: now, im getting an error that says clearState is not defined.

Comment: Yeah because you did not define or import it anywhere inside that document.

Comment: its on the actions files, just like how I call the fbLogin()

Comment: Yeah except that you wrapped that call into a `this.props.dispatch(clearState())` that is not even there. First because there is no prop `dispatch` in your component and second because the name `clearState` is nowhere defined inside that document. See my updated answer.

Comment: it also works if I put the clearState() inside the 
  fbLoginPress()

Comment: what can I do, to make it work like when I'm putting the clearState() on the fbLoginPress. Because there is no error If it is on an onPress() function.

Comment: What do you mean with that? Your issue is how you try to dispatch your `clearState` action. the `connect()` did already wrap it into a dispatch call and it also doesn't pass dispatch as a prop into your component. Just change that line to `this.props.clearState()` instead of your totally incorrect line.

Comment: Oh nevermind, Its already working thank you! I just followed the answer you've given thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162780/discussion-between-drailan-john-terrible-and-trixn).